# Does Minitest have something similar to allow_any_instance_of from RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, minitest

From [Docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-99/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class)

> rspec-mocks provides two methods, `allow_any_instance_of` and
>   `expect_any_instance_of`, that will allow you to stub or mock any
>   instance of a class. They are used in place of allow or expect:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:name).and_return("Wibble")
```

Is there something close to this feature to mock method for all instances of class with `Minitest`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Minitest docs you can only mock single instances.

https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#mocks-

Without seeing the whole code it's hard to judge but might be that your architecture could be improved. For instance you could use dependency injection to avoid the `allow_any_instance_of` and also make your class more extensible.

Instead of doing

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @widget = Widget.new
  end

  def name
    widget.name
  end
end
```

and doing in your test

```rb
it "does expect name" do
  allow_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:name).and_return("Wibble")

  Foo.new.name
end
```

You could inject the widget class like this

```rb
class Foo
  def initialize(widget_class = Widget)
    @widget = widget_class.new
  end

  def name
    widget.name
  end
end
```

and in your spec

```rb
it "does expect name" do
  widget = double()
  widget.stub(:name) { 'a name' }

  foo = Foo.new(widget)

  expect(foo.name).to eq('a name')
end
```

The code is now follows open-closed principle and is more extensible. But hard to judge without seeing your code if this is a viable solution for you.

Summarised this in a blog article here https://sourcediving.com/testing-external-dependencies-using-dependency-injection-ad06496d8cb6

Comment: Thank you! In this question I am not looking for actual solution for specific project, so there is actually no code to share nor architecture to improve. And example is not mine, it is from RSpec docs.

Comment: Alright, I think my answer is still valid though and often if you find it hard to test something (like stubbing any instance) it's good to step back and think if your program has the best architecture. In my answer I outlined one possible solution to make your program more testable.

Comment: There is no program at all and there are no problems with testing. Question is about comparison of two testing frameworks. That type of stabbing available both in RSpec and Mocha and is quite handy in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

After an year, I found the detailed answer for this question: there is no such feature in minitest and [here](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/pull/245) is why:

1. It doesn't fit the vision of Minispec authors
2. It can break the behavior of `stub` in some cases.

But there is a [gem](https://github.com/codeodor/minitest-stub_any_instance) that  adds `stub_any_instance` for the scope of block. The gem is also listed in [Known Extensions](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#label-Known+Extensions-3A) of Minitest.