# Ruby stub 3 class inside minitest - NoMethodError: undefined method allow_any_instance_of

Tags: ruby, minitest

I want to test my pure Ruby lambda handler which looks like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  payload = Parsers::IncomingEvents.new(event: event).call
  ln_response = LN::Api.new(payload: payload).create_quiz
  Responses::CreateQuiz.new(ln_response: ln_response, event: event).call

   { statusCode: 200, body: { message: event }.to_json }
end
```

To do so I'm using below minitest test:

```
require 'pry'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'active_support'

require_relative '../../src/Quiz_create/app'

module QuizCreate
  class HandlerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

    test 'lambda_handler' do
      allow_any_instance_of(Parsers::IncomingEvents::CreateQuiz).to receive(:call)
      allow_any_instance_of(LexisNexis::Api).to receive(:call)
      allow_any_instance_of(Parsers::Responses::CreateQuiz).to receive(:call)

      assert_response :success, lambda_handler(event: event, context: '')
    end

    def event
      File.read('events/event.json')
    end
  end
end
```

But instead of expected results I'm getting an error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `allow_any_instance_of' for #QuizCreate::HandlerTest:0x00007fe4d61268e0

Comment: https://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ExampleMethods%3Aallow_any_instance_of and you are using minitest.

Comment: Maybe this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62430417/does-minitest-have-something-similar-to-allow-any-instance-of-from-rspec

Comment: @razvans I don't have the expect syntax

Comment: @mr_muscle - you should use `Minitest::Mock.new` for mocking in minitest. Check out this https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#mocks-